# Unable to lookup EJBContext within embedded GlassFish 3.1

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, enterprise

i am writing some junit tests, using an EJBContainer. All works fine, except getting the EJBContext within the stateless beans. I need this context to obtain user role information. Tried to get the context both ways:

```
@Resource private javax.ejb.EJBContext ctx;
```

This leads to an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
EJBContext ctx = (EJBContext) ic.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
```

Fails to look up the context (javax.naming.NamingException).

I followed the recommendations given [here](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15837) for adding the jndi.properties. According to [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645) the file is red. Any ideas why this happens? The bean works within a real environment.

Some more information about my setup:

- Windows 7 x64
- Current Java 6 SDK x32
- JUnit 4.10
- glassfish-embedded-all 3.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't Glassfish related. I copied the file "javaee-endorsed-api-6.0.jar" into my sdk endorsed folder a while ago to get use of the

```
@Resource(lookup = ... )
```

annotation in my Eclipse IDE. After the removal of it, all worked.